# Stream was not writeable (StreamWriter)

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to remove specific line from file on IsolatedStorage but I'm still receiving the "Stream was not writeable" from following method:

```
public async static void RemoveFavoriteFromFile(int id)
{
    string favoriteFilename = Globals.FavoriteFilepath;
    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var folder = await local.GetFolderAsync("DataFolder");
    var file = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(Globals.FavoriteFilepath);
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {                
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (String.Compare(line, id.ToString()) == 0)
                    continue;
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on line `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))`

Could anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I would mainly ask you to advice me how to remove specific line from existing file, no matter what I created already. Main issue for me in meaning of understanding is that how to write/edit a file which I firstly need to read for finding the specific line.

Comment: You cannot read and write from/to a text stream at the same time, the file content would be hopelessly jumbled.  The name "OpenStreamForReadAsync" ought to bring that point home, that stream is only readable.  Don't try to find an "OpenStreamForReadWriteAsync" method, it doesn't exist.

Comment: "Why when I open stream for read only I can't write to it" is not really answerable question in terms acceptable on SO. Please clarify what additional information you need to understand that error message. If you are looking for help in removing line - please update your question so it clear what you need help with and what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you guys for the clarification. I've edited my origin post with additional question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and writing to the same file at the same time is always a bad idea.

Either write to a swap file "filename_swap.txt".  After it has finished writing the entire file, delete the original file and rename the "filename_swap.txt" to the original file (basically replacing it).

Or you can read the entire file into a buffer, close the file.  Make your changes to said buffer then open the file again for writing.  This time, write the entire content of the modified buffer.

---

So lets modularize your program

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// read the specific file into a string buffer
private async Task<string> ReadFileIntoBuffer(string fileName)
{
    string buffer = "";                                                                  // our buffer

    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;           // local folder
    var folder = await local.GetFolderAsync("DataFolder");                               // sub folder

    // open the file for reading                        
    using (Stream s = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(fileName))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            buffer = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    // return the buffer
    return buffer;
}

// write the string buffer to a specific file
private async Task<bool> WriteBufferToFile(string fileName, string buffer)
{
    try
    {

        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;           // local folder
        var folder = await local.GetFolderAsync("DataFolder");                               // sub folder

        // open the file for writing
        using (Stream s = await folder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                await sw.WriteAsync(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error_message = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

```
// New Delete Lines function based off your old one
private string DeleteLines(string input_buffer, int id)
{
    string output_buffer = "";

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input_buffer))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                if (String.Compare(line, id.ToString()) == 0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    // add it to the output_buffer plus the newline
                    output_buffer += (line + "\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return output_buffer;
}
```

---

If you have trouble understanding a problem it generally a good idea to break it into smaller parts and debug from there.